# Validation message displayed by default

Tags: angularjs, validation

I enter the page and I can see the validation message immediately.

```
   <div ng-class="{'has-error': test.$invalid}" class="form-group" >
         <input id="field" name="field" required class="form-control" ng-model="field" type="text"/>
         <div class="help-block error" ng-show="test.field.$error.required">Required</div>
      </div>
```

[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/QJ7Qps?p=preview)

How can avoid that ?

Comment: Is this what you want?[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/iLoErbnxrANfjL4TR93s?p=preview) If so, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is essentially with respect to the fact that the condition for 
`ng-show` is only `test.field.$error.required`.

**What's the problem with this?**

Even when the page loads, the field is still not a valid email id.

**So, what's the fix?**

You need to check that the user has actually clicked on the field and the field is no longer `pristine`.

**How do we do that?**

In the `ng-show`, add the following condition.

```
test.field.$error.required && test.field.$dirty
```

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/iLoErbnxrANfjL4TR93s?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add a check to see if the input has been touched too.

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': test.$invalid}" class="form-group" >
     <input id="field" name="field" required class="form-control" ng-model="field" type="text"/>
     <div class="help-block error" ng-show="test.field.$error.required && test.field.$touched">Required</div>
  </div>
```